# Empty jqGrid using JSON

Tags: javascript, json, jsp

The jqGrid is empty.  The jqGrid pager says "No records to view."  The server is returning what looks to be a correctly formatted JSON string.  I defined a JSONReader to match my JSON string format, but still I get an empty grid.  Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the JSON string from the server:

```
{"JSONObj":{"totalpages":"1","currpage":"1","totalrecords":"1","rows":[{"id":"1","cell":["num1","Vendor1"]}]}}
```

Here is the source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-    strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>JSON Example</title>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="grid.locale-en.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-ui-1.9.0.custom.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ui.jqgrid.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript">

      jQuery(document).ready(function () {
         jQuery("#vendorGrid2").jqGrid({
             jsonReader : {
                 root:"rows",
                 total: "totalpages",
                 page: "currpage",
                 records: "totalrecords",
                   cell: "cell", 
                   id: "id"
                },
           pager: $("#vendorGrid2_pager"),
           rowNum:1,
           rowList:[10,20,30],
           datatype: "json",
           viewrecords:true,
           url: "getJSONVendorList",  // call the struts2 action in jsonexample.xml
           gridModel:"JSONObj",       // the object that gets returned containing the grid data
           height: 250,
           colNames:['ID', 'Name'],
           colModel:[
               {name:'num',index:'num', width:200, sorttype:"int"},
               {name:'name',index:'name', width:500, sorttype:"string"}
           ],
           multiselect: false,
           height: "100%",
           caption: "Vendor List",
              //loadComplete: function(data){alert('loaded');},
              loadError: function(xhr,status,error){alert(status+" "+error);}, 
       });

         // this works when datatype:"local"
         //jQuery("#vendorGrid2").addRowData("1", {num:"1", name:"Dallas Vendor"});
         //jQuery("#vendorGrid2").addRowData("2", {num:"2", name:"Ft. Worth Vendor"});
     });

    </script>

</head>
<body>

JSON Example

<div id="gridInfo">
    <table id="vendorGrid2"></table>
    <div id="vendorGrid2_pager"></div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question for the benefit of others who might have the same problem:

The Java class was building a JSON object with a variable named JSONObj using a JSON library (jar).  Doing so would create a JSON string inside a JSON string, hence the 'extra' string "JSONObj" at the beginning of the Object.  This was NOT the way to go.
The proper way is to use the struts2 JSON plugin (struts2-json-plugin-2.1.8.jar).  This plugin takes the entire java class and converts it to a JSON object.  Class properties and public getters and setters (POJO/java bean) must be used in order to implement the class properly.  No need to "build" a JSON object in the class.
This is more of a java/struts2/JSON concept than a specific code issue, but I posted the java class anyway:

```
package autobasic;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import autobasic.beans.VendorBean;
import autobasic.db.DbVendorList;
import autobasic.exception.AutobasicException.AutobasicDBException;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class VendorListActionSupport extends ActionSupport
{

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(VendorListActionSupport.class);
   private String currpage = "1";
   private String totalpages = "1"; 
   private String totalrecords = "2"; 
   private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> rows = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

   public String returnJSON()
   {
      getVendorList();
      return SUCCESS;
   }

   void getVendorList()
   {
      try
      {
         DbVendorList dbVendorList = new DbVendorList();
         List<VendorBean> vendorList = null;
         vendorList = dbVendorList.getVendorList();  // load the list
         totalrecords = Integer.toString(vendorList.size());

         ArrayList<String> items = null;

         for (VendorBean vb : vendorList)
         {
            items = new ArrayList<String>();
            items.add(vb.getID());
            items.add(vb.getName());
            items.add(vb.getCity());
            items.add(vb.getPhone());
            rows.add(items);
         }
      }
      catch (AutobasicDBException e)
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   public String getCurrpage()
   {
      return currpage;
   }

   public String getTotalpages()
   {
      return totalpages;
   }
   public String getTotalrecords()
   {
      return totalrecords;
   }

   public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> getRows()
   {
      return rows;
   }
}
```